# What charger does the surface pro 2 use?

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro

As far as I am aware there is only one kind of charger spec (volt and amps) that works with the surface pro 2.

As far as I know the charger spec is: 12 V 3.6A. Is there anything other than this for the surface pro 2?

I've been looking around for official specs and found none that clearly specifies it.

Comment: "Is there anything other than this for the surface pro 2?" - Not officially

Comment: surely there must be something official? At least in terms of the spec

Comment: Are you asking what the specifications are for the charger?

Comment: yes. That is what I am asking.